# Sails Orm Hook Timeout/not connecting to postgres database on AWS EC2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, sails.js, sails-postgresql

I am currently preparing to put my web application for production. I'm using an Amazon EC2 on Redhat and have a Postgres AWS RDS in the same VPC. I cant seem to connect to the database or to a local one running on the same EC2. I have had no issues while running and testing my app on my local mac and another physical server in our office that runs Redhat 7.

I'm running the 'sails lift' command with my models set to migrate:'alter' so that it can properly set up the Database with my models and configurations, however it gets hung on a 'Waiting...' command in the middle of the orm hook as in the image.

[Problematic Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKvAz.png)

```
default: {

  adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  user: 'exampleuser',
  password: 'thepassword',
  database: 'newdb',
},
```

I can connect to my RDS database and the local one using psql without any issues and with PGadmin. This exactly datastores setup works with my Mac and with our physical Redhat server using their own respective local postgres instances. On the Amazon EC2s however Im running into the problem from the image.

I have also tried running a complete base sails app made with 'sails new newBaseApp' and set up the datastore in that to connect to the local postgres database on the ec2 server. It has the exact same problem.

Comment: Did you try running it with increased `hookTimeout`? Like this - `sails lift --hookTimeout=120000`. Also are you running in development or production mode? It is not advised to run migrations in `alter` mode in production. Can you try running it while migrations is set to `safe`?

Comment: I tried with a hookTimeout of over 1 hour and it still wouldn't connect. I was trying to run `alter` on development mode once, to the configure the freshly created database but nothing seemed to connect to the database whether on production or development and on safe/alter/drop. In the end I found that in the `pg` module, connections were properly being created in the connect() function, so I manually open a connection when that function is called. This seems to have solved the issue completely for now.